# Test a recursive method

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I want test a method

```
public function get($key)
{
    if (!($time = $this->driver->get($key))) {
        if ($key == self::LAST_UPDATE_KEY) {
            $time = new \DateTime();
            $this->driver->set($key, $time);
        } else {
            $time = $this->get(self::LAST_UPDATE_KEY); // need test this condition
        }
    }

    return $time;
}
```

The first request data from the driver should return null, while the second meaning is necessary to me.

I write a test

```
public function testGetEmpty()
{
    $time = new \DateTime();
    $driver_mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('MyDriver')
        ->getMock();
    $driver_mock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->with('foo')
        ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    $driver_mock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->with(Keeper::LAST_UPDATE_KEY)
        ->will($this->returnValue($time));

    $obj = new Keeper($driver_mock);
    $this->assertEquals($time, $obj->get('foo'));
}
```

on execute return a error

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:get> when invoked 1 time(s)
Parameter 0 for invocation MyDriver::get('foo') does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'last-update'
+'foo'
```

Long time i did not write the unit tests, and many forgot. Help me understand.

Comment: found a solution. need to use $this->at(0) and $this->at(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need use `$this->at(0)` and `$this->at(1)`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still looking for a guidance on this one and you are not sure where to use `at()` this needs to be set as part of `expects`, using the example from the answer, it should look like this.

```
public function testGetEmpty()
{
    $time = new \DateTime();
    $driver_mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('MyDriver')
        ->getMock();
    $driver_mock
        ->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('get')
        ->with('foo')
        ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    $driver_mock
        ->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('get')
        ->with(Keeper::LAST_UPDATE_KEY)
        ->will($this->returnValue($time));

    $obj = new Keeper($driver_mock);
    $this->assertEquals($time, $obj->get('foo'));
}
```

In this context, the `at` will define when each invocation should be used.