# How to test a method which calls itself?

Tags: php, unit-testing

Given this code:

```
function testMe($a)
{
    if ($a)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->testMe(true);
    }
}
```

`testMe()` cannot be mocked, because then I cant call it. On the other hand, it must be mocked…

Comment: Unit tests verify the expected output. You mock objects when they aren't being tested. So I don't see the problem here.

Comment: I must mock "testMe" to find out whether it was called with true, or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24467719/1165509

Comment: The fact that this function is recursive is an implementation detail. A unit test verify a function as a black box, and should be entirely independent of the implementation.

Comment: so then how should the test look alike? (100% coverage)

Comment: When you mock an object you are verifying not that object, but the code that called it. Unit tests should isolate the code it's testing and mock objects are way to achieve that.

Comment: @JohnSmith make sure to write the function to be as independent as possible and unit test that function with all branch possibilities, then you'll have 100% coverage.

Comment: This is a bad implementation: the function will ever return `true`. If you pass `false` it will return itself with a fixed `true` value. So, if you test a call `testMe(false)` you'll get a 100% coverage because the two conditions of the `if` will anyway be called. Please, post the real code as I suspect this implementation is too much simple and doesn't show the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your question has some philosophical potential. I'll try to answer it the way you ask it but before, allow me to comment on your comprehension:

> `testMe()` cannot be mocked, because then I cant call it. *On the other hand, it must be mocked…* [italics by me]

The unfinished sentence is wrong. You probably sensed it already because you didn't finish it. In a unit test you don't mock the unit. So you put the unit under test, and the unit is the method. That is the smallest part (unit) that can be tested.

What perhaps actually creates a bit of confusion is the recursion within the method.

So you actually ask how to unit-test recursion or a single method call within that recursion. But do you really need to test it?

I would say no. And that is because the recursion is an implementation detail of the method. From the outside it should not make any difference if you exchange the internal algorithm from recursion to a stack based loop for example.

But despite the fact I say you don't need that (and I hope you already have understood the argumentation I outlined), it technically *is* possible for your very specific scenario to test such a method-call without re-writing the code under test by re-binding `$this`. Then you can replace the subject under test (`$this`) with a mock when called. So that you have two methods: The one to test and the mocked one that is accessible via `$this->testMe()`.

This could be done by instantiating the subject under test, create a mock, use [PHP's reflection to obtain the closure of `testMe()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getclosure.php) then [re-bind `$this` on the closure](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) to the mock and then call the closure for your test assertions.

I would not call this a unit-test any longer because as I outlined earlier, you're testing internals / privates, so you can use it more to actually test fragments of the recursion under certain circumstances and other similar detailed things that will more actually proof / debug fragments of code. You normally only need that under very specific circumstances when code is really high valuable.

Don't use your little confusion about the recursion to think this is an entirely important place to test on it's own. But if you want to get your fingers dirty, it's perhaps something worth to play with to learn about PHP reflection, closures and re-binding `$this`.